# How to give multi line input in c without using array

Tags: c, io, factorial

I want to return the factorial of many numbers taken input at 1 time for example
first line of terminal ask how many numbers for factorial to be return then from second line, user enters the number in each line,this should be done without using array please help i am stucked here

```
Input
    3
    4
    5
    2
```

Here is Output

```
 Output
    24
    120
    2
```

Comment: Hint: use `realloc()`. period.

Comment: @shreesh first of all make me clear that how are you taking many input for factorial at one time and where are you storing it...

Comment: What did you try? Why the "without array" requirement? Does a heap memory zone count as an array?

Answer (score 0):

You might use [readline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) (e.g. on Linux) or [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (on POSIX) -or `fgets` everywhere- to read 
 the line, and [strtol(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) to parse it. You could have a `do`...`while` loop using [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html) (to be called *after* some input function) as a stop condition.

Also, [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3.html) (and related functions like `scanf̀  or`sscanf̀ ) return the number of successfully scanned items, and you should test it if using these functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf,stdin) != NULL)
{
   // Use `atoi(buf)` to get your integers
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework problem, or one from a text book.

Problems of this type usually do not require that you accept all the input before producing any output. even though the input and output are listed separately, your program is allowed to interleave its reading and writing processes.

so you can use scanf, or any other method to read the numbers one at a time and then 
produce the apropiate output after reading each number.

for this problem you won't be needing an array.